# jQuery Mobile - Load MyCss after trigger

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile, triggers

I finally found the correct command to refresh my stuff.
So what I am doing is, changing my div `contentindex` dynamically with `$load` like this:

```
$("#contentindex").load("offline/indexoffline.html", function() {
                $('#contentindex').appendTo('.ui-page').trigger('create');  
                });
```

This applies the jQM css on my elements, but sadly it messes up MyCss, as you can see in the picture. The left one is without jQM css, the right one is with my buggy css:

```
#start {
text-align: center;
position: fixed;
top: 30%;
left: 0;
right: 0;}
#startbutton {
position: fixed;
width: 80% !important;
left: 10%;
top: 55%;
}
```

http://oi41.tinypic.com/j9rn0p.jpg

I hope you can help me, I have no idea how to fix this. :(
Thank you very much.

**EDIT**:More code:
On my index.html I have a button that runs this function:

```
$("#contentindex").load("offline/indexoffline.html", function() {
            $('#contentindex').appendTo('.ui-page').trigger('create');
            });
```

`contentindex` is the id of the div between header and footer.
Now I load this html snippet in:

```
<style>
#start {
text-align: center;
position: fixed;
top: 30%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}

#startbutton {
position: fixed;
width: 80% !important;
left: 10%;
top: 55%;
  }


  </style>
  <article data-role="content">
        <h3 id="start">Drücke Start,<br> um eine neue Runde zu starten.</h3>
        <button id="startbutton" type="button" data-role="button"   onclick="newround()">Start</button>
    </article>
```

Now when I `trigger` the css of `startbutton` transforms in jQuery Mobile, but also resets position. So I guess I need to make an extra file for my css stuff and apply this one after the trigger happened. But how can I do this? :(

Comment: Do you have `id='startbutton'` attribute for button which will be loadede from `offline/indexoffline.html` ?

Comment: Yes, my css works as you can see on the left image. But somehow it gets resetted when I trigger. I guess I need to apply my css after the trigger, but how do I do this? :/

Comment: @user2437856 show more code. Can you create a jsfiddle for your code?

Comment: I added more code, sorry I tried to get in jsfiddle, but I have no idea how to bind my local css and js files. :( Hope the code snippets help.

Comment: I tried this AFTER the trigger:
`$("head").append("<link id='indexcss' href='offline/indexcss.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />");`, it loads the css, but the button still isn't at its place to be.. ~~
    `

Comment: I just want to trigger my css after I triggered the jQuery css.. :( I just cannot figure out how..

Comment: Okay here's something strange:
The button on the right picture visually is at the top of the page, but functionally it is where I want it to be, so when I over at 70% absolute top and click it fires the button..

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, convert your styles into `.class` and then add them after new elements are enhanced.

```
.start {
  text-align: center !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 30% !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}

.startbutton {
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 80% !important;
  left: 10% !important;
  top: 55% !important;
}
```

And then

```
$("#contentindex").load("offline/indexoffline.html", function() {
  $('#contentindex').appendTo('.ui-page').trigger('create');
  $('#start').addClass('start');
  $('#startbutton').addClass('startbutton');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. :( It loads the css but looks like the right picture.

Comment: @user2437856 try `$('startbutton').closest('div').addClass('startbutton');`